# Why does Fndstr returns an errorlevel code of 0 in a batch file whether string is found or not?

Tags: batch

When using the command "findstr /b" at command line and then checking the errorlevel code immediately next, it works fine. When I do the same in a batch file it only returns an error code of 0.

Example:

myfile.txt contains the value "E2B-01-07,5974,3211"

```
findstr /b XXX myfile.txt
echo %errorlevel%
```

This code will incorrectly display 0 in a batch file but correctly display 1 at the command prompt.

Comment: Cannot duplicate - in a `.bat` file the echo returns `1`. Is your errorlevel test placed immediately following the findstr?

Comment: Michael Harvey, you solution worked. The For loop is doing exactaly what I expected it to do. Thank very much for your assistance.

Comment: @Kamil - my answer was a comment first of all; I changed it to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

if you are doing this in a bracket block (FOR loop, IF block) then you need to have [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled before the structure:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

and use exclamation points around the variable name - `!errorlevel!`

e.g.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (*.txt) do (
    echo File:       %%A
    findstr /b "E2B-01-07,5974,3211" "%%A"
    echo Errorlevel: !errorlevel!
)
```